# Conditional expectation regarding sensitivity

Tags: conditional-probability, sensitivity-specificity

Sensitivity is given the disease, the test is positive, i.e. $P(T^+ | D^+)$. Suppose the sensitivity of a test is 0.99. Then $1-P(T^+ | D^+) = 0.01$ But what does this $0.01$ represent?  $P(T^- | D^+)$ or $P(T^+ | D^-)$?

Comment: If you go back to basic probability theory, you'll find that the answer is $P(T^- | D^+)$. Use $P(A^c) = 1 - P(A)$ and the definition of conditional probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(T^+|D^+) + P(T^-|D^+) = 1$

$1 - P(T^+|D^+) = P(T^-|D^+)$

The way to interpret this is: $D^+$ has already happened. Either $T^-$ or $T^+$ must occur. Since they are mutually exclusive, the probabilities of them occurring must add to $1$.

Comment: +1 for your answer. I was unfamiliar with the notation $T^-$ meaning 'test negative' until a friendly user pointed it out to me. I guess it is a ML abbreviation. In my field test performance measures (in this case FN) are used all the time, and that's why I felt so strongly about it. $T^-$ and $T^+$ would be read as "true negative" and "true positive".

Comment: Yes, I read your answer and thought there was some confusion going on! Thanks for the upvote.